# Resizing/Cropping existed images in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Is it possible that I can resize/crop using a new image custom size in wp?

Context: In my website, I have uploaded hundreds of images and now I want to create a new Custom Image size but it won't apply. As I have known that resizing and cropping an images in wordpress applies only in a new uploaded image, just like in this code below:

```
function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'gallery-image' => __('gallery-image'),
    'portfoliopin-item' => __('portfoliopin-item'),
    ) );
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'gallery-image', 588, 402, true );
}
```

My question now is that:

**It is possible that I can resize/crop an existed images using a custom image size name, just like the code above?**

Comment: I think you should used following plugin, It's provide Lot's of functionality And it also satisfied your requirement.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/

Answer (score 2):

You need to regenerate image sizes.

This plugin does what you need and also it deletes non existing old image sizes.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

After you activate the plugin all you need is to click to a button and it does all the work.